# Shifts in 2 32-bit registers

Tags: c, assembly, x86

```
void rotate( unsigned long mask[], int rotateCnt );
```

This function rotates the current 64-bit mask (mask[]) by `rotateCnt` places. If the `rotateCnt` is positive, rotate left; if the `rotateCnt` is negative, rotate right. Only the lower 6 bits of the `rotateCnt` should be used for the `rotateCnt`.

But I have to do the rotate, in 2 32-bit registers that simulates 1 64 bit register, logically performing 64 bit operations across two 32-bit registers. They told me to do 2 loops, but I can't figure this out? Any h

Comment: I believe part of your question has been cut off. Though it looks like you wanted it to end with "Any help?"

Comment: You haven't specified what CPU you're working with.

Comment: Im working with a x86 processor SunOS 5.10

Comment: I assume that this is homework?

Comment: @Brasa619: You should tell your teachers that using assembly like this is totally the wrong thing to do. Assembly is about doing things efficiently*. Using a loop here is very inefficient. (*Note: even if you don't have a compiler for a particular CPU, it happens, then you'd still be aiming for efficiency).

Comment: @Skizz: but learning assembly is what needs to occur before you can use assembly effectively.  You have to learn to walk before you can run. And that may be the stage this class is in.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: The instruction set is the simplest part of assembly programming. Understanding the architecture is the hard part. Once you understand how the registers and memory work together (including stacks, addressing modes, i/o and such like) then you can understand any instruction. Give the students the complete instruction set and let them work out the best way to achieve the desired result. I remember when the 386 came out, it was easy to understand the new instructions but the privilege levels and updated segment handling was a harder as it changed the fundamental behaviour of the CPU

Answer (score 4):

As you're using x86, take a look at [shld and shrd](http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/shld_shrd.html). You won't need loops (why they asked for loops is beyond me).

**Update**

Here's a DevStudio 2005 style function that uses inline assembler to do what you want. Do not present this as a solution without fully understanding how it all works (especially how the negative counts do a right rotate) because it will be incredibly easy for your teachers to spot that you copied this without knowing how it works (i.e. Teacher: "How does this work?", You: "Errr..." => FAIL).

```
void Rotate
(
  unsigned *value, // pointer to two 32bit integers
  int count        // number of bits to rotate: >= 0 left, < 0 = right
)
{
  __asm
  {
    mov esi,value
    mov eax,[esi]
    mov edx,[esi+4]
    mov ecx,count
    mov ebx,eax
    shld eax,edx,cl
    shld edx,ebx,cl
    test cl,32
    jz noswap
    xchg edx,eax
noswap:
    mov [esi],eax
    mov [esi+4],edx
  }
}
```

Comment: They want us to implement it using two loops, one if the rotateCnt is positive rotate it left; if the rotateCnt is negative rotate right.

Comment: @Brasa619: Yeah, but why a loop at all? The x86 has multi-bit shifts and rotates.

Comment: I agree with skizz, shld/shrd is a much better answer if you're going to writing real assembly code.  Failing that, "shld 1" can be easily simulated using rol and rcl (rotate with carry left), and a loop will let you do N bits.  Similarly for shrd.

Comment: I'd assume that the loop requirement is there for similar reasons that multiplication is taught as repeated addition.  Or maybe iteration, dealing with carries, and/or stashing temporary values safely may be the point of the exercise more than what's the most efficient way to rotate.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably quicker instructions for this, but here's the idea... If you're rotating left:

1. take the most significant `rotateCnt` bits from the high-order register, shift them right `32-rotateCnt` bits, and stash the result somewhere
2. shift the high-order register left by `rotateCnt` bits
3. take the most significant `rotateCnt` bits from the low-order register, shift them left `32-rotateCnt` bits, and add the result to the high-order register
4. shift the remaining bits in the low-order register left by `rotateCnt` bits and add the bits that you saved in step 1

I'm sure you can see how to extend this process to any number of registers. If `rotateCnt` can be larger than 32 bits, you'll have to work a little harder, especially in the general case (n registers instead of just 2). One thing that may help is to notice that shifting left by n bits is the same as shifting right by (size-n) bits.

From your comments, I see that you're supposed to use a loop. You can always apply the rotate procedure described above 1 bit at a time for rotateCnt iterations. In that case, you'd obviously change `rotateCnt` in the description above to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

A single bit rotate is simply a single bit shift with carries out of one word being applied to the next word with a special case that a carry out of the high word gets applied to the low word.

It may help you to consider a picture of what needs to happen in certain scenarios.  I'll use 4-bit words below and I'll assume the rotate is to the left; the same concepts apply to whatever word size you might use:

```
// Note '-' in the carry column means "don't care"
//
// starting value (in binary):

              'high'             'low'
     carry     word     carry     word

        -     1 0 0 0     -     1 0 0 1

//  after shift left of each word:

        1     0 0 0 0      1    0 0 1 0

//  apply the carry out of the low word
//      to the high word:

        1     0 0 0 1      -    0 0 1 0    

//  apply the carry out of the high word
//      to the low word

        -     0 0 0 1      -    0 0 1 1
```

To use this basic operation to rotate multiple positions, just loop the appropriate number of times.

Note that this can be done without any loops at all by applying the right set of bitmasks and shifts. Basically you can get all the bits that will carry out of a word in one shot without looping. A looping version is probably more straightforward to implement - you might consider doing that first and using it as a verification test if you decide to improve it to a non-looping version.

Answer (score 1):

think about how you would do this in C for example, then translate that to asm.

Using 32 bit variables to do a single bit shift left for example, assuming ra is the upper 32 bits and rb the lower

```
if(rb&0x80000000) { ra<<=1; ra|=1; rb<<=1 }
else              { ra<<=1; rb<<=1; }
```

For a rotate you might do something along these lines

```
if(rb&0x80000000)
{
  if(ra&0x80000000) { ra<<=1; ra|=1; rb<<=1: rb|=1; }
  else              { ra<<=1; ra|=1; rb<<=1; }
}
else
{
  if(ra&0x80000000) { ra<<=1; rb<<=1: rb|=1; }
  else              { ra<<=1; rb<<=1; }
}
```

You can then wrap a loop around one of those and do it N times.

Or say an 8 bit shift left

```
ra=(ra<<8)|(rb>>(32-8));
rb<<=8;
```

Or say an N bit shift left

```
ra=(ra<<=n)|(rb>>(32-n));
rb<<=n;
```

Or an n bit rotate left (which is the same as a 32-n bit rotate right)(there is a reason why some processors only have a rotate right and the left is virtual or vice versa).

```
temp=ra>>(32-n);
ra=(ra<<=n)|(rb>>(32-n));
rb=(rb<<<=n)|temp;
```

Then look at the instruction set and see what is available and matches what you are doing.

In short to shift bits you need to take the bit on one side and put it in the next bit.  If you align yourself on some boundary like a variable or register there is no difference you take the bit from one side and shift it into the other, it may take more code as the instruction set or programming language doesnt support it directly doesnt mean you cant do it.  Just like you can perform a 2048 bit multiply on an 8 bit processor with no multiply instruction, just takes more code than other processors, but it is very doable.

Comment: My main question is how to shift the bits left or right taking into account of the rotateCnt that is between -63 to +63.

Comment: How do we take that into account in the SPARC architecture since it only has ld and st. How do i store that bit that is carried from the MSB of one riegister to the LSB of the other register.

Comment: If the number is negative make it positive and shift one direction if it is positive shift the other direction...Perhaps the two loops comes from one bit at a time, one loop for left and another loop for right.

Comment: are you implying that SPARC processors cannot run C programs?  Cannot run unix or linux, etc because they cannot implement an AND operation, or compare with zero, or a shift (left shift can be implemented with add or multiply btw, right shift with a divide or with a loop using left shifts ands and compares).  there are a myriad of ways to solve this problem.  choose one.

Comment: I just showed you how to do that, look at the code, if (rb&0x80000000) then rb<<=1; rb|=1;  These are very simple to implement in almost every assembly language.  If it is an 8 bit processor then you just have to do it 8 times.  the assembly btw makes it much much easier if you have a shift rotate through carry and you want to go one bit at a time. if not then just implement it one of the other ways.